# Python Regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am having hard time to figure out a regexp in python

I have this line: `EQI+C:100:a5a6a9a9a9a6a6a6+365+59+CV:6`

And sometimes the part

```
:a5a6a9a9a9a6a6a6
365
```

can be missing.

I am using python regrexp. How can I match this part optionally? I tried `(? : [a-zA-Z0-9])` but it does not seem to work.

Comment: What is the format of this thing?

Comment: Is the 'part' supposed to be there? How do you know its the 'part' if its not there?

Comment: For instance, `[:a3569+]+` matches the 'part'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably better to split the string on the `:` and then try to match regexes on the substrings rather than trying to match the whole string.

Or even something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "EQI+C:100:a5a6a9a9a9a6a6a6+365+59+CV:6"
>>> [x for x in a.split("+") if re.search(".*:([a-z]+)",x)]
['C:100:a5a6a9a9a9a6a6a6']
>>>
```

Comment: I started with that spliting with + because the data block are seperated with +  but I was trying to use regular expression because it has to match some exact data Just to let u know I can have for example :

EQI+datablocl1+datablocK2+datablocK3+datablocK4

and the datablock have lot of data seperated with : sometime the data can be misisng and if I use split I may not know that

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example.  You can iterate over the split parts and if it's not there,  the resulting array from the list comprehension would be zero length.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use regexes at all for this problem:

```
s = "EQI+C:100:a5a6a9a9a9a6a6a6+365+59+CV:6"
fields = s.split(":")
data = fields[2].split("+")
```

Comment: I started with that spliting with + because the data block are seperated with +  but I was trying to use regular expression because it has to match some exact data Just to let u know I can have for example :

EQI+datablocl1+datablocK2+datablocK3+datablocK4

and the datablock have lot of data seperated with : sometime the data can be misisng and if I use split I may not know that

Comment: Unless you give us the exact specifications of your data format (including examples of input and expected output), we can't help you.